# Django: Require admin approval for patch and post

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, admin

I'm trying to write my REST API in Django so that if someone makes a patch or post it will require someone with access to Django's admin panel to actually write the changes, but it'll be pending and visible to the admin till then, is this possible? Or do I have to create a model for the pending request then make the patch and post create new entities?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the request user somewhere, several solutions:

- A new model in your database
- A new field `is_validated` on your model
- Store that in cache (not safe)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything that @Zulu said in his answer (except using the cache, don't think that would be a great idea).

I think your best bet would be (assuming I understand your overall goal) would be to create a model that stores the history of changes. From there, every change would be able to maintain state, and then your view/viewset can simply pull from the data that was most recently validated. Hopefully that makes sense and can help you out overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new field in the model to show an approved or pending status

```
approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This field should not be included in your model serializer, but in your model admin. You could also use a queryset to show only objects that have not been approved in the admin panel.